# Why does "Q_FUNC_INFO "/" __FILE__" fail in Qt Creator/macOS?

Tags: c++, qt

This compiles fine in Qt Creator/Windows:

```
foo(Q_FUNC_INFO "/" __FILE__);
```

But on the Mac, using Qt Creator as IDE/compiler, I get error:

```
error: expected ')'
```

These also fail on the Mac:

```
foo(Q_FUNC_INFO ## "/" ## __FILE__);
foo(Q_FUNC_INFO __FILE__);
```

Is there a way of concatenating function name and file name?

Comment: Just for fun, I looked into [woboq.org](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qcompilerdetection.h.html). For most compilers, `Q_FUNC_INFO` expands to `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`. On Mac, I assume you use clang. (?) So, this condenses to the question how clang defines `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, I believe. Btw. did you try as well `foo(std::string(Q_FUNC_INFO) + "/" + __FILE__)`? This might work if `Q_FUNC_INFO` provides something which is convertible to `std::string`. (I came to this idea as there is `__func__` which is a variable, and hence all your attempts would fail in this case.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how OP defined `foo()` but (for the sake of simplicity) I will assume that it might be:

```
void foo(std::string_view text);
```

I must admit that I don't have experience with Mac OS but I heard the common compilers are clang or gcc.

I had a look on [**woboq.org**](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qcompilerdetection.h.html) to see how `Q_FUNC_INFO` is defined. There are a lot of nested `#if`s and `#elif`s but after a while of digging, I came to the conclusion that the effective should be:

```
#elif defined(__GNU_C__)
```

…

```
#  define Q_FUNC_INFO       __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
```

So, the question is actually: How is `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` defined?

I couldn't find anything about clang but [The GCC doc.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html) is quite clear about this:

> In C, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ is yet another name for __func__, except that at file scope (or, in C++, namespace scope), it evaluates to the string "top level". In addition, in C++, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ contains the signature of the function as well as its bare name.

…

> These identifiers are variables, not preprocessor macros, and may not be used to initialize char arrays or be concatenated with string literals.

This explains why all the attempts of OP *must* have been failed.

The fix is actually simple:

```
foo(std::string(Q_FUNC_INFO) + "/" + __FILE__);
```

and I expect that this fix should work on other compilers as well.

MCVE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#  define Q_FUNC_INFO __FUNCSIG__
#else 
#  define Q_FUNC_INFO __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
#endif

void foo(std::string_view text) { std::cout << text << '\n'; }

int main()
{
  foo(std::string(Q_FUNC_INFO) + "/" + __FILE__);
}
```

[image: Demo on Compiler Explorer]

Comment: BRILLIANT! Thanks, that solved the problem. Sorry I should have mentioned that it's foo(const char*). So the solution is foo((std::string(Q_FUNC_INFO) + "/" + ＿FILE＿).c_str()); Thank you for your thorough and generous analysis.